# Should I always use fully qualified class name in PHP?

Tags: php, autoload, psr-0

I see some example code such as

```
$log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
```

Why not always use the  fully qualified class name instead?

```
$log = new \Monolog\Logger('name');
```

So you don't need to worry if this file is being used in whatever namespace, right?

Answer (score 2):

You would use a fully qualified namespace if you are referencing a class from a separate namespace. For example:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;

class ClassName
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->foobar = new Monolog\Logger;
    }
}
```

In this situation, `$this->foobar` would be resolved to an instance of `Foo\Bar\Monolog\Logger`.

If Monolog is a completely different package from `Foo\Bar`, we don't want this to happen, so we use the fully qualififed namespace.

If you used the fully-qualified namespace of `\Monolog\Logger`, `$this->foobar` would be an instance of `Monolog\Logger`.

Use the fully-qualified namespaces if you are using classes from a separate package/namespace in a namespace of your own. 
Use just the qualified namespace if you are using classes within the same namespace.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I think it's still relevant. I also have some questions about its usage. What about the `use ...` and the `... extends ...` statements? The examples in the [Name resolution rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) page don't include these two cases. One can infer, but they are not explicit about it.